# Magento: missing Dataflow options in Admin Panel

Tags: admin, importexport, admin-panel, magento-1.4

Magento 1.4.2 Admin Panel

Under `System > Import / Export` I have the following options:

```
Profiles
Advanced Profiles
```

I feel like I am missing `Dataflow - Profiles` and `Dataflow - Advanced Profiles`.

Were these present in Magento 1.4.2?

And if they were, how do I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature first appeared in in CE 1.5.